# Takes in two sorted lists and outputs a sorted list that is their union

Tags: python, performance, sorting, mergesort

> Write a function that takes in two sorted lists and outputs a sorted
>   list that is their union

Could anyone help me to improve this code and make it more user-friendly? We are not supposed to use any built-in Python functions, but rather develop our own efficient algorithms.

```
def answer(list1, list2):

    len1 = len(list1)
    len2 = len(list2)

    final_list = []
    j = 0
    k = 0

    for i in range(len1+len2):

        if k == len1:
            final_list.append(list2[j])
            j += 1
            continue

        if j == len2:
            final_list.append(list1[k])
            k += 1
            continue

        if list1[k] < list2[j]:
            final_list.append(list1[k])
            k += 1

        else:
            final_list.append(list2[j])
            j += 1

    return final_list


print answer([1, 2 , 17, 18, 100], [3, 3, 4, 5, 15, 19, 20, 101])
```

Comment: Could you please join the 2nd Monitor and talk about your requirements?

Comment: @Caridorc You might want to include a link to it: [The 2nd Monitor, Code Review General Chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor)

Comment: *"We are not supposed to use any built-in Python functions"* you may want to clarify that and say exactly what functions are prohibited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pick better names for your variables. Definitely `answer` should be something else, like `sorted_union`. `result` would be better than `final_list`. And `list1` and `len1` aren't great, though you have limited options there.

You should also add a docstring. They're basically string literals that appear at the start of a class or function. They're programmatically accessible comments that will allow you to see what the function does, and you already have one in your brief, so just add the syntax to include it:

```
def answer(list1, list2):
    """Takes two sorted lists and returns their union as a sorted list."""
```

Also since you call `for i in range` but don't need `i`, a commonly accepted Python style is to actually use `_` instead of `i`. Using an underscore signals that you don't need the value, it's just there to fit the `for` loop syntax.

You actually could shortcircuit the loop when `j` or `k` have reached the end. You know you'll no longer need anything but the rest of `list2` in this case:

```
    if k == len1:
        final_list.append(list2[j])
        j += 1
        continue
```

So why not just use `extend` to add the rest of `list2` on to `final_list` and `break` the loop?

```
    if k == len1:
        final_list.extend(list2[j:])
        break
```

Answer (score 4):

I think your solution is ok.

Instead of using `continue`, consider using `if..elif..elif..else`:

```
if k >= len1:
  ...
elif j >= len2:
  ...
elif ...:
  ...
else:
  ...
```

Also, the test `k >= len1` is an example of "defensive programming". It protects against `k` skipping over `len1` when being incremented in the loop. Also, the expression `list1[k]` doesn't make sense unless `k < len1`, and the negation of that is `k >= len1` which is another good reason to use it in the if statement.

If you've learned about `xrange()` then I would use that instead of `range()` -- see these SO answers:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135041/should-you-always-favor-xrange-over-range

Otherwise it looks good!

Answer (score 3):

What your code is doing is typically described as **merging** both lists.  The word **union** sounds like the set operation, where repeated values should appear only once.

Assuming your interpretation is correct, you typically want to minimize the amount of work done in the inner loop of any algorithm.  In your case, this is typically done by not handling the items of one list once the other is exhausted inside that loop, but afterwards.

Also, the typical way of merging is that, in case of a tie, the value from the first list goes into the final list first. This is mostly irrelevant for your case, but it is a good habit to write these things conforming to that norm, so that if you ever find yourself writing code for an indirect mergesort, you willt be less likely to make it non-stable by mistake.

```
while idx1 < len(list1) and idx2 < len(list2):
    if list2[idx2] < list1[idx1]:
        final_list.append(list2[idx2])
        idx2 += 1
    else:  # Ties are solved in favor of the first list
        final_list.append(list1[idx1])
        idx1 += 1
while idx1 < len(list1):
    final_list.append(list1[idx1])
    idx1 += 1
while idx2 < len(list2):
    final_list.append(list2[idx2])
    idx2 += 1
```

Answer (score 3):

**Efficiency**

- If you can use the `append` method I would assume you are also allowed to use the `extend` method. In that case, I'd rewrite your first two control statements, checking if you've gotten to the end of one of the original lists, like so (also making the control statements more readable/succinct/performant with an `elif`:

  ```
  if k == len1:
      final_list.extend(list2[j:])
      break
  elif j == len2:
      final_list.extend(list1[k:])
      break
  ```

  I may have missed something in the logic, but I think this should get to what you want and spare you a lot of unneeded iterations once you have exhausted one of the original lists.
- Use `iterators` instead of `lists` when possible. Here that would be using `xrange` instead of `range` in your for loop. Not super important, but it's good practice.

**Readability**

- You could definitely use better variable names, and I think @Jaime's use of `idx1` and `idx2` is a good example of this. Since you have `list1` doesn't it make more sense to have `idx1` rather than a reader having to guess whether `j` or `k` applies to `list1`? Similarly, a better name for `answer` would be `unionOfTwoLists` and `final_list` could be `unionList`.
- I'd similarly echo @Jaime's comment that the name `union` is quite confusing. At first I was thinking your function was wrong because it allowed duplicated. Whether you keep the name or not, this is a good issue to address inn your docstring, to save future code readers confusion, which brings me to the next point
- You need some comments, at least a `docstring` for your function.
- Why don't you format your code so that the related `if...else` branches are closer together? They look as independent of one another as the other control statements, but they aren't. It's nice when the eye can see just from the form of the code which chunks are 'units' of a sort.

Comment: Thanks man!! Sadly I can't accept two answers. Thumbs up for an amazing feedback!

Answer (score 1):

I think if we set instead of the sort then it will be considered as a union in case of + in the case of the same elements in both lists it will just add the elements twice in final list

Comment: Is `set` a build in python function? That would invalidate one of the requirements.